# Printf is displaying value of variable

Tags: shell

I am working on a small ksh. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
export car=mercedes
export owner=sam
touch /tmp/who-is-owner
# now I need to redirect value of these vars to file in
# a specific pattern without displaying values so

printf "$car-owner=$owner" > /tmp/who-is-owner

exit 0
```

This script is suppose to redirect output to file, but it ends up with 
`Ksh :.:line 1 mercedes-owner=sam: no parent`

I have tried {}, () and '' around variable but no success.

Fairly new to scripting, appreciate suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: It is suppose to redirect value as "mercedes-owner=Sam" to file and I will need to source that file at different times to set this value as env variable.

Comment: Your code works on my machine without issue. It creates/overwrites a file named `/tmp/who-is-owner` with one line `mercedes-owner=sam`

Comment: Thanks, I tried script. It worked. To source output file, I am using alias from ~/.kshrc "alias driver='source  /tmp/who-is-owner' . Seems like it is failing at this point.